# Error validating form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm getting the following error when trying to validate my form:

```
'this.0.form' is null or not an object
```

I'm using the latest jQuery and jQuery.Validate, and jQuery.Validate.Unobtrusive (via NuGet).

Here is the code. Where is the error coming from?

```
@model URIntake.IntakeFormViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Claim Information";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="SubmissionForm">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "UrIntake", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "UrIntakeForm"}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FormSubmitter.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FormSubmitter.FirstName)

    <div id="SubmissionButtons" class="right">
        <input type="button" onclick="SubmitForm()" value="Submit" />
        <input type="button" onclick="CancelForm()" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
}
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function CancelForm() {
        document.location = "/";
    }

    function SubmitForm() {
        $("UrIntakeForm").valid();
     }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery selector for the form omits the `#` sign. The [jQuery ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) should include a `#` like so:

```
function SubmitForm() {
    $("#UrIntakeForm").valid(); // "#UrIntakeForm" instead of "UrIntakeForm"
 }
```

Otherwise you are applying the `valid()` method to an empty jQuery object, which results with the error you've specified.

Comment: Duh! Thanks for the extra set of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector is wrong

```
   function SubmitForm() {
        $("#UrIntakeForm").valid();
     }
```

add a hash (#) to the selector to identify it as an id